# How do i loop over a List from the end?

Tags: c#

This will loop from the first index 0 , 1 , 2 ,3....
I want to loop from the last index 51 , 50 , 49....

```
for (int x = 0; x < data.Count(); x++)
```

What i need to loop over the List backwards from the end to start.

Comment: `for(int i = data.Count(); i-->0;){}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to start from `count -1`, change the condition to greater or equal to zero and use decrement `--` instead of increment. Read this MSDN article [for (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) for more understanding of for loop.

```
for (int x = data.Count()-1 ; x >=0 ; x--)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in only accessing each item then you can do this:

```
foreach (var item in data.Reverse())
{
    /* do stuff with each item */
}
```

The readability of this code will, in 99.99% of all cases, outweigh the performance impact.

Comment: Note: This adds an extra overhead of calculating the reverse order list. (Personally I only like to use `Reverse` when displaying a list to the user)

Comment: @Sayse - I answer questions relating to performance issues quite often and I very rarely see anything like this causing a performance issue that is in any way significant. The readability of this code will, in 99.99% of all cases, outweigh the performance impact.

Comment: I agree its probably a very minor performance impact, but there is still a performance impact, and I would hope most programmers would understand what the backwards for loop looks like

Comment: +1 for Enigmativity.  The perf impact will be negligible unless you are dealing with very large structures and it's certainly more readable.